# subsring in swift 4.0 from index 0 to required index

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have a string:

```
"08 sept 2017 10:56 AM"
```

I want to divide this string into two strings: `dateStr` and `timeStr`.

I tried this for `dateStr`:

```
let createdDateStr = transactionModel.created_on! //"08 sept 2017 10:56 AM"
let dateCount = createdDateStr.characters.count - 8
let timeStr = createdDateStr.substring(dateCount)
```

It works, but I don't know how to do the same for `dateStr`.

I have a string extention:

```
func substring(_ from: Int) -> String {
    let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: from)
    return String(self[start ..< endIndex])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **partial ranges** to to that. Try this extension:

```
func substring(to: Int) -> String {
    let end = index(startIndex, offsetBy: to)
    return String(self[..< end])
}
```

---

```
let dateCount = createdDateStr.characters.count - 8
let dateStr = createdDateStr.substring(to: dateCount)
```